Setting up Cascading WMS using SSL PKIX path building failed error
We have created a layer that should pull from a remote ArcGIS server that requires TLS authentication.
If I use my certificate or a registered server certificate to directly access the URL from my web browser I get a good capabilities response.
When I put the URL into GeoServer for a cascading WMS service layer and then go to preview the layer using GeoServer web interface I get a file download prompt with a file that contains:
<?xml version"1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ServiceExceptionReport>
<ServiceException> Internal error
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:  unable to find valid certification path to requested target
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>

I am pretty familiar with setting up SSL certificate/trust stores each application/system seems to have its own method of defining which ones to use.  I can not find anywhere that tells me how to tell GeoServer which certificate to use to identify itself when making outgoing connections or which truststore to use to validate the remote server's certificate.
We are running on Tomcat on a RedHat 7 platform...  the appropriate chain CA certificates exist in the system cacerts file which is linked back to the Java cacerts file...
Where do I setup the certificate and truststore for GeoServer to use when it makes an outgoing connection for a cascading request?

Error sounds like Tomcat not recognizing the ArcGIS server certificate/chain.  GeoServer doesn't handle the SSL handshake as far as I am aware

I agree with that "appearance", so I verified the certificate chain was in cacerts that Tomcat should be looking at...   but this is an outgoing request from geoserver, tomcat will absolutely handle all inbound requests... I am not sure tomcat gets involved with outgoing requests from an application...
